# jquery query parameter parsing - "=" in query string breaks query string up

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, parameters, query-string

I'm trying to parse parameters from a query string using [this jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/getqueryparam) and this sample query string:

```
http://test.com/?xnJTqqWEclJnnPEvWH&cid=3DF3-00-=63-D4-DA-2F-91-6B-39-39-75-E4-C1-B7-28-12&mid=3D93-36-14-46-4D-52-9E-48-17-=6A-50-13-56-FA-0A-06&PROMO_MONTH=3D201106
```

Using the code for the plugin:

```
console.log($.getQueryParam( "cid" ));
```

The cid gets divided at the first instance of the "=" sign - so instead of:

```
3DF3-00-=63-D4-DA-2F-91-6B-39-39-75-E4-C1-B7-28-12
```

I get

```
3DF3-00-
```

Is this normal behavior? Does the equals sign do something in particular in this query string? If not, how do I parse this query string so that I get the entire parameter?

Comment: Yes, the equal sign is special as it separates the parameter name from the value. However, a better parser would probably detect two "consecutive" `=` (no `&` in between). Still, afaik, it has to be encoded if you want to use it in a value.

Comment: I can't change the values being passed in the query string. I can only manipulate what I receive from the URL.

Comment: You cannot change or encode the query string?  Is there a guarantee that it will always be the last parameter? (I am thinking that you might have to string parse it, and not use the jQuery function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [gup](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) instead. I see it used in quite a few places and it works well. It is very simple. Note that I made a small change in the fiddle to shoehorn in the url. The code below is what you should actually use.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/trqJ8/

```
gup('cid');

function gup( name )
{
 name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
 var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
 var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
 var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
 if( results == null )
    return "";
 else
    return results[1];
}
```

Comment: nice! And no plugin required!

Comment: Mind you, this does not support arrays, etc. Also it should have: `return decodeURIComponent(results[1]);` there is no easy way to do it. I decided to use [jquery.query.js](https://gist.github.com/2975441).

Answer (score 2):

The plugin itself wasn't written to accommodate a string like that. The culprit is the following piece of code...

```
if (params[0] == param) {
 return params[1] || '';
}
```

Shortly before this step the plugin script does a `split()` on the equal sign creating an array. The above code snippet should be changed to something like the following to make your query retrieval work...

```
if (params[0] == param) {
    var paramOut = '';
    for (var p = 1; p < params.length; p++) {
        paramOut += params[p] + '=';
    }
    return paramOut.substr(0, paramOut.length - 1); // to remove the trailing equal sign
} else {
    return '';
}
```

Here is the plugin patched with my revisions in case you're still interested in using it...

```
(function($){$.getQueryParam=function(param){var pairs=location.search.substring(1).split('&');for(var i=0;i<pairs.length;i++){var params=pairs[i].split('=');if(params[0]==param){var paramOut='';for(var p=1;p<params.length;p++){paramOut+=params[p]+'=';}return paramOut.substr(0, paramOut.length-1);}else{return '';}}return undefined;};})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 for treating the condition as opposed to the symptom. You should notify the plugin author!

Answer (score 1):

It is. "=" is used as a delimiter of parts of the query, so you should escape it.
Yandex search engine does it so:
http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%3D